# param type in route of express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In express.js, if I have this route in my server side

```
router.get('/ad/:id', (req, res) => {

    const { id } = req.params

    Ad.getAd(id, (err, resp) => {
        if(err){
            return handleError('Failed to load an ad', res)
        }

        res.json({
            success: true,
            result: resp
        })
    })
})
```

and it worked fine I want to load a detail ad like `example.com/ad/123` where id is 123. But I can't do `example.com/ad/create` anymore, any way to check the type of the param?

Comment: Why you just don't create separate route above for /ad/create? In this case, if it will match, your route /ad/:id will not be triggered, and if you will have /ad/123 then create route will not be triggered. You have two logically different operations, so they should be in a different routes and even with a different HTTP methods.

Comment: Why not use a `POST` to create your ad? `GET` is due to retrieve resources not create them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create separate route for it. Place before `/ad/:id` route, because it's catching all requests like `/ad/*`.

```
router.get('/ad/create', (req, res) => { /* some work */ })
router.get('/ad/:id', (req, res) => { /* some work */ })
```

---

Since you mentioned you are building a SPA, you must redirect all GET requests to react-router:

```
app.get("*", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/path/to/index.html")
})
```

Also you can prepend `api` to all back-end endpoints to prevent ambiguity.

```
router.get('/api/ad/create', (req, res) => { /* some work */ })
router.get('/api/ad/:id', (req, res) => { /* some work */ })
```

Comment: extra route is not an elegant solution, i'm using react-router

Comment: @Jenny Mok if the two URL should do completely different things (i.e. Create a resource and retrieve a resource) then it makes sense to have different functions handle them.  I'm not sure how that's not elegant in your eyes.

Comment: @OzgurGUL `app.get("*", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/path/to/index.html")
})` for this where to find my index.html? I separate my server code from my front end code.

Answer (score 6):

```
router.get('/ad/:id', (req, res,next) => {
  const { id } = req.params
  if(! parseInt(id,10)){
     return next();//skip this route if not a number
  }
  //its a number
});
```